# Creating a editable table with Element Select in column

Tags: plugin-development, form, table-field

First of all, I'm starting in Craft in general so I'm having a hard time with things that might be basic.

I want to create a editable table with a Element Select in a column. Like:

[image]

I already have the possibility to add custom fields, but I don't now how to set up the template.

```
{{ forms.editableTable({
    id: 'timetable',
    name: 'timetable',
    required: false,
    cols: {
        name: {
            heading: "Name" |t,
            type: "select" |t,
            options: {
                'area-x' : 'Area X',
                'area-y' : 'Area Y',
                'area-z' : 'Area Z',
            }
        },
        artists: {
            heading: "Artists" |t,
            type: "elementSelect" |t,
        }
    },
    rows: ///
}) }}
```

But of course that doesn't work.

Can anyone light up the way?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but have you seen https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable?

Comment: Actually it does! Yesterday I got into the Craft Slack group, and someone suggested Super Table. And it was the answer to my prayers! Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind adding that as an official answer, Jorge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my specific case, [Super Table](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) was the answer.

You can also check [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo)